# find the source of reconvergent fanouts in a DAG

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

if we have graph like:

[image: c17_graph(b)]

the rencovergent nodes are nodes 10 and 11.
by reconvergent nodes i mean the parents of that node come from a common source node.

in the given graph the parents of node 10 are nodes 7, 8 and they both have node 6 as source node(source of reconvergence)
and for node 11 the source node would be node 4.

my question is if we know which nodes are reconvergent nodes in the DAG how could we find the source nodes of their parents?

for my graph structure i use adjacency list representation available at [geekforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-search-or-dfs-for-a-graph/)

i've tried this:

```
 if(Node is reconvergent_node)
 for each parents of Node
      Do DFS(0, parents[i]) // depth first search from primary source till we reach the parent node 
  if the paths from 0 to parents[i] (which extracted from DFS) have common node mark that node as source node
```

is this algorithm correct? although i have not get the right results yet...

if it's correct i thinks it's limited to reconvergent nodes with max of two parents.
what if we have reconvergent_node which has five parents such that parents[1,2] have common source and parents[3,4,5] have different source node?
what should i do in this case?

any suggestion are welcome.
thank you

Comment: I think you need to define what you are looking for more clearly.  It sounds like you want dominators, but I'm not sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)

Comment: i think it can also be referred to as Dominator!

Comment: but not necessarily dominates all the entries of dominated node.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do this? i really have no idea how to this.so please help me...

Comment: Still don't know what you want, except that it's not a dominator

Comment: if we have two or more specific node in DAG (which are the parents of reconvergent node). i want to check if they have common node if we back trace their path to primary inputs of the Graph(common ancestor) and store that common node

Comment: i mean in the given graph if we want the source of nodes(8, 9) we get 4, and if we want the source of nodes(7, 8) we get 6

Comment: Why not simply compare the paths of the "reconvergent node" and find the common node(s) ?

Comment: Really i dont know which approach is efficient. but i thought this is the best way to perform this. you mean i use BFS and stop seachrching when we visit the  "reconvergent node" ?